# Is it permissible in Islam to interbreed between two different species of animals to make new variation in animal's offspring?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh

Nowadays people make experiments and perform interbreeding to obtain new variation in animals. Like we have make horse and donkey interbreeding to produce a mule. Is this permissible, although Allah has sent all the living things in this world in pairs while people make from them new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mules existed in the time of the Prophet (SAW) and he even owned many, and there doesn't seem to be any place where he discourages them or says that breeding them is forbidden:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) did not leave anything behind him after his death except **a white mule**, his arms and a piece of land which he left to be given in charity. ([Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/89))
>
> On the Day of Khaibar, the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) prohibited eating domesticated donkeys, **the meat of mules**, every predator that possesses canine teeth, and every bird that possesses talons. ([Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/18/18))

So, the default is that it is not forbidden.

Comment: even mules are mentioned in the quran, sura nahl 16:8

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. It's surprising that you got a green tick

Comment: @Afiq That's not the point of my answer. The ahadith are simply to show mules existed in his time.

Comment: Yes but simply existing does not prove the allowance or prohibition of something.

Comment: The ahadith is simply about dietary statutes. Cross-breeding is a different matter.

Comment: @Afiq You are right, but them existing in front of him and the Prophet saying nothing about them proves they are allowed. Plus, the verse in the Quran.

Comment: That's very conjectural. Like I said simply existing does not mean that the Prophet SAW allowed or disallowed cross-breeding. Mules have been around for centuries before the Prophet SAW. It was the end result of cross-breeding a horse and a donkey. This is a change in the creation of Allah SWT

Comment: We should know that it's prohibited, despite the Prophet SAW being silent of it in this case, by virtue of the rule of not changing creation.

Comment: Here's proof: https://sunnah.com/search?q=Mate+donkey+horse  for the prohibition

Comment: @Afiq If you wish, write an answer quoting fatawa or scholarly statements. As for the verse in the Quran, it cannot be more clear that breeding and using mules is halal. Allah attributes their creation to Himself. Why would he do that if their creation was something haram? 

As for the hadith, it seems to be specifically for Ahlul-Bayt. ("not consume charity" for example is only for the Ahlul-Bayt.) See https://sunnah.com/urn/1101420. And it can also simply be advice due to the rarity of horses in their circumstance.